# Magento Connect Manager Setting Error

Tags: magento, programming-languages

Need an urgent solution about magento Error....
Am getting an error message in Magento 1.5.0.1 version at Magento Connect Manager ... I couldn't install magento extensions ...

The error msg shows as :

**Warning: Your Magento folder does not have sufficient write permissions.
If you wish to proceed downloading Magento packages online, please set all Magento folders to have writable permission for the web server user (example: apache) or set up FTP Connection on the Magento Connect Manager Settings tab.**

Whereas, I have changed the file permission from our end to 777

The locations are : 
app/etc
app/code
var
media

Also, i have uploaded Magento files and folder directly into the root directory .. so, there is no Magento folder existed in the root directory..

Please give some soln ..
Thanks

Comment: File permissions *shouldn't be* 0777, as that lets any user on the system write to the files.  They should be 0775 at best, with the files belonging to the same group as the web server, or owned by the web server.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your web root directory (ie /var/www/public_html/) is actually read and write by apache so having it be the owner and set your permissions to 755 or 775.  I bet you don't have a folder/file in the root that Magento Connect it trying to create but cant because the web root permissions are wrong not your magento file permissions themselves (that was my problem at least) ... and yes you shouldn't be 777 everything that is bad.